# How can I insert rows in a table while filling out an infopath form

Tags: infopath, form

I am creating form in InfoPath. I am trying to setup the form with 3 columns per row, and the user needs to be able to add rows a needed.

Comment: How does this relate to SharePoint?

Comment: @ErinL I think InfoPath [questions](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infopath) are valid.  OP, you're looking for a repeating table/section.

Comment: @wjervis InfoPath questions are valid if they relate to SharePoint. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. It's also important to know because repeating table/sections are more complicated if being used in SharePoint.

Comment: @ErinL My experience with InfoPath is rather limited, so if there's a way to use it outside the context of SharePoint, I don't know that.

Comment: @wjervis Let's continue this conversation in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44160/wjervis

Comment: May be you can look into the embedded code on button click.

Answer (score 0):

MWilson – If your question relates to an InfoPath form saved to a Form library on SharePoint, and you want to create new rows and promote these new fields as columns in SharePoint, you won’t be able to.

To achieve similar functionality, you would need to use a [List Form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-SharePoint-list-form-c1f9283d-f704-4bbe-a8aa-827425ab31ae).  List Forms are out of the box list forms that have been opened, edited, and display in an InfoPath template.  These are just a few of the gotcha’s with List Forms:

- As a best practice for a list where a List Form will be designed, the column limit is approximately 60.  If you require more than 60 fields in your form, a straight InfoPath form is your best answer.
- There must be a one-to-one relationship for data entered in a List Form, therefore you cannot use repeating tables and repeating sections, which is what you refer to in your question.  You must:  1) set a cap for the number of additional “rows” a user can add (for example three “rows” only), 2) create duplicate columns such as “Option 1 – Hotel,” Option 2 – Hotel,” Option 3 – Hotel,” 3) and use InfoPath Rules to show options 2 – 3 as “Add another row.”
- Managed Metadata fields cannot be used in List Forms, or InfoPath forms.